# Why ListView shows Object.object instead of data?

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have some code here with short explanation in grey (coding comments):

```
namespace FridgeApp
{
    [Activity( MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MenuActivity : Activity
    {
        public string content;
        ListView productsListView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

           SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Menu);

            //GETTING ACCES TO XML FILES
            AssetManager assets = this.Assets;

            //PLACING CONTENT OF XML FILE "products.xml" TO 'content' VARIABLE
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("products.xml")))
            {
                content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            List<Product> _productsList = ProductsFromXml();

            //CONVERTING FROM LIST TO AN ARRAY
            Array prdcts = _productsList.ToArray();

            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

            //BY CLICKING A BUTTON APP SETS ANOTHER LAYOUT AND DISPLAYS A LIST OF PRODUCTS
            button.Click += delegate
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ProductsList);
                productsListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
                productsListView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice, prdcts );
                productsListView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
            };                          
        }

        //THIS MEHOD READS ACTUAL DATA FROM XML FILE "products.xml" AND PLACES IT IN  LIST 'productsList' 
        public List<Product> ProductsFromXml()
        {
            List<Product> productsList = new List<Product>();

            XmlDocument productsXml = new XmlDocument();
            productsXml.LoadXml(content);

            XmlNode root = productsXml.SelectSingleNode("CurrentProducts");
            XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("Product");
            foreach (XmlNode n in nodeList)
            {
                Product p = new Product();
                p.Name = n.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
                p.Quantity = n.SelectSingleNode("Quantity").InnerText;
                productsList.Add(p);
            }
            return productsList;
        }
    }
}
```

For every product 'name' and 'quantity' there is a class with these paramterers created called 'Product'.
There is an XML file:

```
<CurrentProducts>
<Product>
    <Name>Apple</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Banana</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Bread</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Butter</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Cucumber</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Milk</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Cheese</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Smoked Sausage</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Tomato</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Egg</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Chicken</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Chocolate</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Potato</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Onion</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Lettuce</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Sour Cream</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Tomato Sauce</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Carrot</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Orange Juice</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Salmon</Name>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Flavour</Name>
    <Quantity>1 kg</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Salt</Name>
    <Quantity>1 kg</Quantity>
</Product>
<Product>
    <Name>Sugar</Name>
    <Quantity>1 kg</Quantity>
</Product>
```

And here is a photo of emulator screen when button clicked and content of an Array displayed:

[image: photo]

The question is, why it displays `Products.Product` instead of the actual products written in `products.xml`?

Here is the code of the class:

```
  public class Product
  { 

    public string Name;
    public string Quantity;
    public MeasurementType UnitMeasure;

    public Product()
    {
    }

    public Product(string _name)
    {
        this.Name = _name;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have debugged, there are no errors, everything goes fine. But the thing is, that the products that are written in xml file doesnt appear on the app screen (as it is seen in a photo). The method, which puts the data from xml file to a list was created in ConsoleApplication and when the list was displayed there, it showed the products which are defined in xml file. And now it shows 'Products.Product'. And that is the thing I'm asking for help.

Comment: as @Uno points out, the ListView doesn't know what to display for your custom class.  By default it will just call ToString() which all C# objects support.  The default behavior of ToString() is to display the name of the class, but you can override this behavior by providing your own ToString() implementation.

Comment: So, as far as I understand, I just basically need to add public override string ToString() to my Product class

Comment: Yes, just do what @Uno suggested

Answer (score 0):

You should share the code of the `Product` class; I believe the `ListView` is invoking `ToString()` on the product objects and they are just returning the type name as the type doesn't know any better.

Try adding:

```
class Product
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Format your product name here as you want it to be displayed.
        return $"{Name} - {Quantity}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Code of the class above

Comment: @Zilvinas then I believe this is the issue, you should add the `ToString` override.

Comment: I should add it to `Products` class? And where and when should I use it ? :)

Comment: It's implicitly used by the `ListView` internally. You need to add it there because the `ListView` has only the product object as name provider. If you want a better design, you can create a wrapper around the `Product` object just to separate the display logic.